# RegExp: How to exclude whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby-1.8.7

Considering Ruby 1.8.7 or Javascript.

I have the following string: `(GMT+02:00) Istanbul` and I want to capture everything after the `)` (note the whitespace included after the close parentheses)

The regexp I have created is almost working with exception it is including the undesired whitspace.

`\s\D*` => `Istanbul`

How can I fix that and is this regexp for doing this?

**EDIT**

The string can be others, something like `(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa`

In this case, I want `West Central Africa`

So, some answers will not work.

Sorry, I have forgot to mention that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby:

```
irb> line = '(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa'
irb> line.sub(/^.*\)\s/, '')
=> "West Central Africa"
```

In JavaScript:

```
js> var line = '(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa'
js> line.replace(/^.*\)\s/, '')
West Central Africa
```

Answer (score 1):

*Positive Look-behind Assertion* is one option.

```
(?<=\s)[\D]+
```

(tested with python regex lib)

To extract the first word after a GMT offset definition like the one in your example...

```
(?<=\([\D]{3}[\+\-][\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\)\s)[\D]+
```

Comment: Which bit is complicated? No doubt the second pattern could be shortened, but it isn't complicated!

Comment: No need to have such a long regexp to accomplish what the user have asked for. Just this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can stick optional whitespace characters **\s*** in between every other character in your regex. Although granted, it will get a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

`\S+$`

It matches everything that is not a space at the end of the line.

If you want to match only alphabetical character, you can use the following:

`\w+$`

You can test them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
(?<=\s)[\w]*
```

[Check here for your example](http://regexr.com?31gt8)

Answer (score 0):

When you say capture, if you wish to get a named capture, and ignore the rest, you can do the follwing:

```
(?:.+\s)(?<Country>.+)
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple expression:

```
[^)]*\)\s*(\w+)
```

explain:

```
[^)]*        any character except: ')' 
             (0 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

\)           ')'

\s*          whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
             (0 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

\w+          word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) 
             (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```